# Safe implementation on Solidity 0.8.0 of a withdrawal and a refund

Tags: solidity, security, address.transfer, nft

I'm here for asking of a *SECURE* way to implement on solidity 0.8.0 two functions:
1-Withdrawal() which sends all the ether of the smart contract to the owner address. My current implementation is:

```
//send the ethereum on this contract to the owner 
function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        address payable _owner = payable(owner());
        _owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
 }
```

2-Refund() which sends ether to the buyer of my token if the msg.value exceeds the cost of a single token. My current implementation is:

```
function createToken(xxx parameters) payable public {
        require(msg.value >= TokenCost, "not enough ether sent!");
        
        _createToken(xxx parameters);
        
        //refund user if he/she pays more than the singleCarCost value 
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - TokenCost);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!
Simone :P